# Definitions of verbalisations in card games, specifically UNO and DOS

Tags: uno, dos

In the card game DOS, the sequel to UNO, there is a rule stating:

> DOS RULE: If you ever have EXACTLY TWO CARDS in your hand, you must shout out "DOS!" (meaning "two"). If you forget to do so and another player calls out "DOS!" before you do, you must immediately draw two cards as a penalty.If this happens during your turn, do not add the penalty cards to your hand until the end of your turn.

**At what exact moment is it considered that one have "said 'DOS!'"?** *Is simply producing the start of the word "DOS" vocally the moment that I've said it, or can I be caught if my opponent starts to say it to catch me but I finish the word before my opponent? How do other games handle this issue?*

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't say in the rules and since both words ("UNO" & "DOS") are so short it really shouldn't be an issue...

http://www.mattelgames.com/sites/mattel_games/files/2018-03/FRM36-0970-G2_IS_web.pdf

But, I would say that it's quite clear that as soon as someone starts to say the word, no one else is allowed to also say it - but faster.

You could compare it to the first person to press a button or the first person to shout their name in a game show.
*The first person to press the button gets to answer - Not the first person to press and also release the button...

The first person to start saying their name gets to answer - Otherwise the person with a short name would always be favoured over the one with a long name...*

Comment: Do you have any source for that?

Comment: I do think this is the fairer way to play, but I'm not certain the button metaphor is a strong argument. I could make the opposite claim by saying that *starting* to say the word is analogous to my hand beginning to move toward the button and *finishing* the word is my hand actually hitting the button.

Answer (score 0):

I usually play where you can say UNO or DOS while you are placing your second or third card respectively. After the card is down, other people can call out UNO (or DOS)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. My question doesn't ask about when you're allowed to say those, I'm asking about what defines having said "UNO!" or "DOS" (start of word, end of word, etc).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything in the rules that specify what constitutes saying "UNO".  You will just have to decide with your playgroup how you want to define it.

Answer (score 0):

That is completely up to your playgroup. Some say start of the word. Some say that whoever says the full word first has it, no matter who started first. Talk to your playgroup and try to agree on a balance.